# I want To Make a Foreign Key Relation Between Java Pojo Class and a Table(which does't hava java class)..?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I Hava a POJO Class with some properties ,among them i want to make a foreign key reference to one of them with a table but this table does't hava pojo class ,so is it possible to make foreign key reference between one pojo and one table ..?

Comment: You can add a constraint between two tables, but not between a Java POJO and a DB table.

Comment: @dunni yes I can do it manually in DB but i want it through programming is it possible?

Comment: The foreign key constraint is defined in the database, between columns of tables. The database doesn't care whether a table is mapped to a Java entity in your code or not.

Comment: If you just want to add a real DB constraint from Java, then I think you can simply run a prepared statement from Java with the proper "alter table table_name add constraint ..." command.

Comment: Research "JDBC". Are you fluent with SQL?